# Laravel Unisharp File Manager Incorrect URL after uploading images

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and [UniSharp File Manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/) version 1.6.

I have setup everything as per docs. I am trying to integrate the file manager independenty. I am using all default configs in config/lfm.php except I have set `"allow_multi_user"` to `false`.

The problem is whenever I am uploading an image and selecting it using the file manager, the url of the uploaded/selected file is showing wrong url like this:

> http://localhost:8000/photosshares/57ac916bada5b.jpg

whereas, the url should be:

> http://localhost:8000/photos/shares/57ac916bada5b.jpg

The url is missing a front slash in it. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug in Unisharp File Manager and it has been reported here:

https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/102

The issue reporter has also found a solution which I am quoting below:

> It worked after I removed the following from
>   vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/views/script.blade.php
>
> if (path.indexOf(ds) === 0) { path = path.substring(1); }

This also solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code (you can find it at line 350 )

```
if (path.indexOf(ds) === 0) {
path = path.substring(1);
}
```

from this file script.blade.php
file path = vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/views/script.blade.php

source https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/102

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me by replacing the code at line 350 (*vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/views/script.blade.php*).

```
if (path !== ds) {
    item_url = item_url + path + ds;
} else {
    item_url = item_url + ds;
}
```